# Am I using usleep correctly or is this a bug?

Tags: c++, linux, usleep

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int var;
int main()
{
    var=1;
    cout << var;
    var++;
    usleep (2000000);
    cout << var;
    return 0;
}
```

So, theoretically, it should print 1, wait 2 seconds, then print 2. Instead, the second I start the program, it waits 2 seconds and then prints 1 and 2. Is this a bug or am I just stupid? (Yes, I am a noob to c++)

Comment: Characters in the cache，try cout<<var<<endl; or use cout.flush()

Comment: FYI, the phrase you're looking for is *buffered I/O*. Check out [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush)

Comment: @paxdiablo Don't gotta be rude.

Comment: Being rude was not my intent, I would hope the smiley at the end of my sentence made that clear. The bottom line is that, almost invariably, it's never a problem with the tried and tested software (like the C++ language) because that's been, well, tried and tested by millions. It's almost always a problem with the code that _hasn't_ been tested by millions.

Answer (score 4):

you probably aren't flushing stdout... try:

```
cout << var << endl;
```

Comment: or alternatively, explicitly flush it with `cout.flush()`

Comment: @jedwards, that is semantically more correct... but for logging this is typically the answer...

Comment: Or, double alternatively, use `<< std::flush;`. While Grady's answer is correct (and often the desired answer), it's important to note it adds a newline that is not present in the original code.

Comment: I'm almost positive `endl` will be perfectly fine for them, just tossing out alternatives.

Comment: both alternatives are not equivalent... first one (`cout.flush()`) flushes the output and you'll get the output `12` with a two seconds interval between the digits.  Second one forces a newline (and a flush, if the output is to a tty) and you'll get both numbers in different lines.